# Number of Pivots in Quick Sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have a code that sorts an array with QuickSort algorithm. My code sorts numbers correctly. However, it can not print the pivots selected at each step. What I want to do is storing the pivots in an array and then print the elements of this array within a function. In my opinion, number of pivots is equal to the length of array-1 at most. Therefore, i declare the NumberOfPivots array with size of 
array.length-1 as in the code below. And the count represents number of pivots selected. Then i try to assign the values as in the Partition method below. Finally by using WritePivots method, i try to print the pivots as in the method below. When i run the code all the elements of the NumberOfPivots array returned as 0. How can I solve this and obtain the pivots by using a method?

```
  int[] NumberOfPivots ;
   int count=0;
  public void QuickSorting(int[]array, int p, int r)
 {
    NumberOfPivots = new int[array.length-1];

    if(p<r)
    {
        int q = Partition(array,p,r);   
        this.QuickSorting(array,p,q);
        this.QuickSorting(array,q+1,r);

    }

} 

public  int Partition(int[] array, int p, int r) {

    int pivot = array[p];
    NumberOfPivots[count] = pivot;
    count++; }

public  void WritePivots()
{
    for(int k : NumberOfPivots)
        System.out.println(k);
}
```

Comment: The array is poorly named. It isn't an array of numbers of pivots. It is an array of pivots.

Comment: An observation: Once a pivot is placed, it is never moved again. So after the partition step, the pivot is at the sorted place. So any pivot can be identified by its index, which provides a simple proof that there are as many pivots as there are array elements, or less if you use a different sort method once the partitions get small enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
NumberOfPivots = new int[array.length-1];
```

Will delete all your pivots each time `QuickSorting()` is called. Initialize the array elsewhere (only once) and it should be working.

btw. please start method names with lowercase letters, looks better and is standard :)